# Creating a Stored Procedure in MySQL using C# code

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create stored procedure in MySQL using following C# code:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (MySqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                using (MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = spscript;

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }

                trans.Commit();
            }
        }
```

and the SP script is as below

```
DROP procedure IF exists SP_GetMyBinWorkflowResult;

CREATE PROCEDURE `SP_GetResult` (p_tablename varchar(100), p_binId int, p_queueId int)
BEGIN
declare whereclause varchar(1000);
declare success  int;
declare @s varchar(4000);

set whereclause = "1=1";
/*prepare string for where clause*/
set whereclause = concat(whereclause, " and queueid=", p_queueId, " and isdeleted = 0 and isassigned = 1  and binid =", p_binId  );

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT count(*) FROM ',p_tablename, ' where ', whereclause);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',p_tablename, ' where ', whereclause);

    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

When I am running this code it gives exception as "Parameter '@s' must be defined".

I have variable @s declared in script. But not sure why it is giving "Parameter '@s' must be defined". Anybody could please help me out to resolve this error.

Thanks.

Comment: The variable `@s` is not necessary to declare. Check: [9.4. User-Defined Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html).

Comment: Even if I dont declare it, I am getting same exception.